# Libgdx - android - accelerometer texture flicker

Tags: android, libgdx, accelerometer

im new on Libgdx(android)..

im trying to use the accelerometer to move a object. (like doodle jump)
The movement works but the object flicker the whole time.

Here is the code:

```
private double getXPosAcc() {
    float XPosAcc = 0;
    float x = Gdx.input.getAccelerometerX();
    float factor;
    float displayWidth = (Gdx.graphics.getWidth() - imgSprite.getWidth());
    factor =  (8f - x); // +8 .. -8 range of accelerometer

    XPosAcc = (displayWidth / 100) * ((100 / 16) * factor);



    return XPosAcc;
}
```

The render methode:

```
@Override
public void render () {
...
imgSprite.setPosition(getXPosAcc(), 100);
...
}
```

Comment: This is normal with an accelerometer. You need to apply a smoothing algorithm. The compass and gyroscope can also be used to improve the results, but gyroscope support hasn't been added to libgdx yet.

Comment: can u explain why it isnt be smooth? must i increase the precision of the accelerometer?

Comment: It's a hardware technology limitation of all accelerometers.